# Is there a way to take a screenshot everytime the key ''Space'' is pressed and released?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I Don't want to press printscreen everytime, I'd like to take a SS everytime space is pressed and released, and said SS saved in a folder.

I've tried with PIL using ImageGrab, but im failing to create more that one SS, to put them in order. ''Image1.jpg'' ''Image2.jpg''

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
while True:0
keyboard.add hotkey('space')
SS = ImageGrab.grab()
save_path = "C:\\Users\\robbie\\Desktop\\prints\\image.jpg"
SS.save(save_path)
```

I've started Python last week and I Am terrible at it.

Comment: Which are you using, Python 2 or 3? You shouldn't tag both.

Comment: you keep saving on same path and overwriting the old image. Either read the previous images from the directory and decide file name according to the that. Or add a random string at the end of filename for uniqueness. Or the simplest just add the current timestamp to the filename. `import time`, then append `time.time()` to filename.

Comment: Sorry ruohola, im also new to stackoverflow, how can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always just overwrite the old screenshot with the new one when you save them with the same name. You can simply add the current time to the filename to make them unique:

```
import datetime

import keyboard
from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        SS = ImageGrab.grab()
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
        save_path = f"C:\\Users\\robbie\\Desktop\\prints\\image{time}.jpg"
        SS.save(save_path)
```

I also changed this to use [`keyboard.is_pressed()`](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.is_pressed), because that's what you actually need for this.

Comment: will fail if script is stopped and started again

Comment: @VaibhavVishal True! Edited to use current time :)

Comment: Im missing something, the ''Invalid Syntax'' error keeps popping up, with a red highlight on the word hotkey. I've also added import keyboard to the code, and the outcome its the same.

Comment: @rimenta Your original code was missing a underscore on `add_hotkey`, I also changed that to use `is_pressed`.

Comment: I've should mentioned the problems that I had experimenting with the keyboard module, I've ''pip install'' everything and Im still getting the ''AttributeError: module 'keyboard' has no attribute 'add_hotkey''' . the keyboard module seems the perfect fit, but has that to it. seems better than tkinter for this issue.

Comment: worth to mention that ''keyboard.is_pressed'' also ''has no attribute''

Comment: @rimenta You didn't name your file `keyboard.py` did you?

Comment: @rimenta The `keyboard` module didn't install correctly then.

Comment: @rimenta Did you also clone the `keyboard` from git? Delete that folder.

Comment: I've had other file named keyboard.py, from when I was studying through ''Automate the boring stuff with Python'' THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @rimenta Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working method:

```
import keyboard as k
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
while True:
    if k.is_pressed("space"):
        SS = ImageGrab.grab()
        save_path = "C:\\Users\\robbie\\Desktop\\prints\\image " + str(time.time()) + ".jpg"
        SS.save(save_path)
```